# How to double quote escape in SQLAlchemy

Tags: security, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I wish to safely pass a schema name that must be double-quote escaped to the database engine, in this case when constructing a GRANT statement I want to pass a variable containing test safely to the database.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "test" TO readuser
```

I'm unsure how to do this from SQLAlchemy.

If it helps I am using psycopg2 to connect to postgreSQL

Answer (score -1):

I've never tried issuing database maintenance queries like `GRANT` through SQLAlchemy. I suppose the ORM won't issue this kind of query, therefore I guess that you want to issue it textually using [Session.execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute). If so, the examples in the documentation are pretty straightforward about how to do it:

```
session.execute(
    "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA :param TO readuser",
    { "param": "test" }
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because params are for values and will be single quote escaped. I did try that before writing this question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the presumption. I didn't realize that single quotes and double quotes could have different meaning in SQL.